# How to make codeigniter application logout after inactive 24 hours?

Tags: codeigniter, session

One of my client project in `CodeIgniter` and he wants to logout application if someone `inactive` on screen after `24 hours`.

I tried to set a variable in a local system `config.php` file.

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;
```

It works in local but on `AWS server`, it does not work. I tried to found a solution for it but not still get it.

Anyone have any idea or solution then it will help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: session expiration has nothing to do with whether someone is inactive. it just expires the session when x number of time has past when the user could still be doing things. what you *might* want is a js script that monitors whether or not the user is on the page doing nothing, if so, you can redirect to a logout script. the downside is if the user navigates away from your site and is thus inactive, the logout script won't run. however you could always run a cron job to remove inactive users and have your js script double as a ping to CI.

Answer (score 0):

```
var set_logout_time = 86400;

if(set_logout_time != ''){
    t = setTimeout(logout,set_logout_time);  
}else{
    t = setTimeout(logout, 240000); 
}

function logout() {
    localStorage.setItem('logout-event', 'logout');
    window.location = '<?= base_url('Dashboard/logout/') ?>';
}
```